# bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js invalid state in Internet Explorer

Tags: bootstrap-table

i am using bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js to add filter in my bootstrap table. Its working fine in chrome but in IE its throwing error "Invalid State"
can anyone tell me wht could be the problem?
here the gimps of  what i am using

Scripts

```
<script src="~/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/assets/bootstrap-table/src/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/bootstrap-table/dist/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js"></script>

through JS i am binding to bootstrap table

signerTable.bootstrapTable
({
                   data: data
                   , filterControl: true
                    , columns: [
{
                             title: 'Plant',
                             field: 'OrgCode',
                             align: 'left',
                             valign: 'top',
                             halign: 'center',
                             searchable: true,
                             sortable: false,
                             filterControl: 'select'
                         },`
]
```

Error Screen Shot
[image]

Error Line in bootstrap-table-filter-control.js
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you include a JSFIDDLE showing your code - makes it much easier for people to assist as we then have a working example of your problem.  [Here is a good list of starter samples to save you time.](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/)